# How can i add generate and scan QR code feature in web apps ?

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-applications, qr-code

how QR code generates and scans feature works on websites, for example, WhatsApp web.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript library called `instascan` 
which allows you to scan QR codes:
https://github.com/schmich/instascan

here you have a live example:
https://schmich.github.io/instascan/